# Ajax Jquery .get dynamical generating Content from .CSV

Tags: jquery, ajax, csv, internet-explorer, get

I've generated content from a `.csv` file and everything works fine in Chrome. But as soon as I'm using IE nothing happens.
I'm using `$.get('file.csv', function(data_unformed) { ... }` to get the content from the `.csv` file.

```html
/* Create Price Tag */
var steuersatz_string = thisRow.split(";")[12, 13]; /* Find Steuersatz in Table */
var preis_netto_string_unformed = thisRow.split(";")[15, 16]; /* Find Price in Table */ 
var preis_netto_string = preis_netto_string_unformed.replace(/\,/g, '.');  /* Replace all "," to "." */

var steuersatz = parseFloat(steuersatz_string); /* String to Float */
var preis_netto = parseFloat(preis_netto_string); /* String to Float */

var preis_brutto_ungerunden = preis_netto*(steuersatz/100+1); 
var preis_brutto = (Math.round(preis_brutto_ungerunden * 100)/100).toFixed(2);  
var preis_big = preis_brutto.split('.')[0];  
var preis_small = preis_brutto.split('.').slice(1).join('.'); 

var aktion_on = thisRow.split("#")[3]; /* Display if On */

if (aktion_on==1) { 
if (Object.keys(preis_small).length < 1) /* Create 2xZero if integer */
{build += '<div class="angebot_preisbox aktionspreis_on"><span class="angebot_preis"><span class="preis_big">' + preis_big + '.' + '</span><span class="preis_small">' + '00' + '</span></span></div>\n';}
```

`Error: Object.keys: argument is not an Object`

Does anyone have a solution?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please can you add any error from the javascript console? Is the file you request really transfered? You can open the dev tools with `F12` and look at the requests/responses and the console.

Comment: Thanks you for the <kbd>F12</kbd> info! That helped me now to detect the error. My function "if (Object.keys(preis_small).length < 1)"
IE Error: Object.keys: This argument is not an object

Comment: You can add the relevant source parts and the _error message_ to your question.

Comment: Excuse me for my mistakes i'm new to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** formed `(Object.keys(preis_small).length < 1)` to `((preis_small).length < 1)` and encoded my .csv file to UTF-8 via Notepad.